# setIcon of JLabel is not working, but setIconImage of JFrame is

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

I am using VS Code and my folder contains one Java file and one image only.

I was trying to set image in JLabel, so first I access the image by:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("img_flag.png"));
```

Then I set this to `JLabel` but nothing appears on my screen.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(img);
```

To confirm that I am accessing the correct image, I set it to the logo of the window and the logo was showing properly.

```
setIconImage(img.getImage());
```

I can't figure out why label can't show the image.

Here is my full code:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Mylable extends JFrame{

    Mylable(){
 
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("img_flag.png"));
        setIconImage(img.getImage());       //working 
        JLabel label = new JLabel(img);     //not working 
        add(label);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        new Mylable();
    }    
}
```

[image: logo is appearing but JLable is not showing]

Comment: Components need to be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is visible.

Comment: Take `setVisible(true);` and move it to the end of the constructor OR you need to call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container you've changed in order to trigger a new layout and paint pass

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is that means I can't make changes on the window once I make it visible?

Comment: *"that means I can't make changes on the window once I make it visible"* No a GUI can be updated with new components in a number of ways, but you want to be certain that it is actually necessary to add components dynamically, as it requires special handling. Given a `JLabel` without a BG color, border, icon or text is invisible, it should not be necessary here. Just add the label when the GUI is created, then set the icon whenever it's needed.

Comment: _Is that means I can't make changes on the window once I make it visible?_ as MadProgrammer commented: _**you need to call revalidate and repaint on the container you've changed in order to trigger a new layout and paint**_